# Missing service account

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My pipeline doesn't start due to error:

```
(8e45efed0ad51300): Workflow failed. Causes: (8e45efed0ad51e7b): There was a problem refreshing your credentials. 
Please check: 
1. Dataflow API is enabled for your project. 
2. There is a robot service account for your project: [project number]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com should have access to your project. If this account does not appear in the permissions tab for your project, contact Dataflow support.
```

I assume that Dataflow API is enabled as I'm able to reach Dataflow monitoring console, so first requirement is fulfilled. Second isn't. There is no a single account in the domain cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com.

Where can I ask for such help without paid support plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disable and then re-enable the Dataflow API for your project that should create the missing service account.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Although I was able to reach Dataflow monitoring console API wasn't enabled at all. Thus my assumption was incorrect - enabling Dataflow API helped.